# How to get a count down timer that will display upon an onlick from one td to another?

Tags: javascript, html, text, timer, countdown

ok so im making a simple  and i am trying to get my td's to display an automatic countdown timer of say 4 hours,6 hours,8 hours but i cannot seem to be able to get it down for the display, i have the timestamp working fine but i cannot figure out what i am doing and missing to get it to display the timer in the second td upon the get time button from the first one... so this is what i have come up with so far...

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Timestamp</title>


<script language="JavaScript">
function getTimeStamp() {
       var now = new Date();
       return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':'
                     + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                     .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
}

</script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="countDown.js">


var seconds = 132360;
function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>


</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000" text="#FFFFFF" background="black_cracked.jpg" bgproperties="fixed">

<div align="center">
  <center>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="780" height="700">
    <tr>
      <td width="751" height="80" colspan="3">
        <p align="center"><font face="ravish" font color="#white" size="12">Timestamp</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td width="141" height="546">
        <div align="Left">
          <table border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="136" bgcolor="#3E3E3E">
            <tr>
              <td width="125" bgcolor="#333333">
                <p align="center"><b><font face="Arial"color="Yellow">Menu</font></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="125" bgcolor="#000000"><font face="Arial" color="Green"><b><a href="file:///C:/Users/Rika/Desktop/Deviants%20Website/Home%20Page/Main%20Page.html">Home</a></b></font></td>
            </tr><tr>
              <td width="125" bgcolor="#000000"><font face="Arial" color="Green"><b><a href="file:///C:/Users/Rika/Desktop/Deviants%20Website/APS/A.P.S..html">A.P.S.</a></b></font></td>
            </tr><tr>
              <td width="125" bgcolor="#000000"><font face="Arial" color="Green"><b><a href="file:///C:/Users/Rika/Desktop/Deviants%20Website/Dragon%20Scale%20Locations/dragon%20scale%20locations.html">Dragon Scale Locations</a></b></font></td>
            </tr><tr>
              <td width="125" bgcolor="#000000"><font face="Arial" color="Green"><b><a href="">link</a></b></font></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div><BR>
        <div align="center">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="136" bgcolor="#333333" height="118">

          </table>
        </div><BR>
        <div align="center">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="136" bgcolor="#3E3E3E">
            <tr>

            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      <td width="462" height="546" valign="top">
        <p align="center"><b><font face="Arial" size="4">Edit Me</font></b></p>
        <table border="2" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" width="700" bgcolor="#3E3E3E" style="background-color: transparent;">
<tr>
<td>Boss Name</td>
<td>Realm</td>
<td>Last Killed On</td>
<td>Next Time to Spawn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td><form>

  <button type="button" onclick="this.form.timeField.value=getTimeStamp()" >Get time stamp</button>
  <input type="text" name="timeField" size="17"></input>
  </form>
</td>
<td>


<input type="text" id="secondPassed" name="countDown"  >
Count Me Down Baby!
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
      </center>
      <p align="left"><b><font face="Arial" font color="#FFFF00" size="3">Edit Me</font></b>

      <div align="center">
        <center>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="416" height="335" bgcolor="#3E3E3E">

        </table>
        </center>
      </div>

  </table>
  </center>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

All im trying to do`` is once the button is pressed in one td to have the auto timer start in the second one right after it...

if anyone can please help me it would be much appreciated...

Comment: please create a JSfiddle for it

Comment: This is what i have saved to my pc and when i run it in firefox it gives the full view of what i am trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/aeC8z/1/

What the main idea is, is to get a count down timer to the onclick in the second td as just a display of a time of 3,4,6,8 etc hours and have it be seperate to each row.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/6Z3RJ/) and let me know if your problem is resolved or do you still want some improvement in this:
js:

```
var seconds = 132360;
function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').value = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').value = "Buzz Buzz";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```